# Integrate Wordpress post in oscommerce

Tags: php, sql

I what to integrate a gallery from WordPress in to oscommerce. Now I am trying to make first,  one menu with a list of posts names from data base that a "gallery type". The selection work fine and return the result. Now I try to integrate it in other php file from oscommerce but my result return only errors. Please help my to integrate my code into other code.
This is the selection from data base and the returns from it.

```
<?php
//db parameters
$localhost = '####';
$db_username = '######';
$db_password = '#######';
$db_database = '1131496_class';

//connect to the database
mysql_connect($localhost, $db_username, $db_password);
@mysql_select_db($db_database) or die("Unable to select database");

//get data from database -- !
$query = "Select * FROM gall_posts WHERE post_type='bw_gallery' AND post_status='publish' ORDER BY id DESC";

$query_result = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_numrows($query_result);

//close database connection
mysql_close();
?>
<?php
//start a loop
for($i=0; $i< $num_rows; $i++){

//assign data to variables, $i is the row number, which increases with each run of the loop
$blog_title = mysql_result($query_result, $i, "post_title");

echo '<li><a href="#">' .$blog_title. '</a></li>';

} //end the for loop
?>
```

and the code where I what to integrate in it is

```
<?php
/*
  $Id$

  osCommerce, Open Source E-Commerce Solutions
  http://www.oscommerce.com

  Copyright (c) 2013 osCommerce

  Released under the GNU General Public License
*/

  class bm_gallery {
    var $code = 'bm_gallery';
    var $group = 'boxes';
    var $title;
    var $description;
    var $sort_order;
    var $enabled = false;

    function bm_gallery() {
      $this->title = MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_TITLE;
      $this->description = MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_DESCRIPTION;

      if ( defined('MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_STATUS') ) {
        $this->sort_order = MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_SORT_ORDER;
        $this->enabled = (MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_STATUS == 'True');

        $this->group = ((MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_CONTENT_PLACEMENT == 'Left Column') ? 'boxes_column_left' : 'boxes_column_right');
      }
    }

    function execute() {
      global $oscTemplate;

      $data = '<div class="ui-widget infoBoxContainer mj-information">' .
              '  <div class="ui-widget-header infoBoxHeading">' . MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_BOX_TITLE . '</div>' .
              '  <div class="ui-widget-content infoBoxContents">' .
              '    <p>Lesen Sie hier was unsere Kunden über uns sagen: </p>' .
              '    <a href="bewertungen.php">' . 'Alle Kundenmeinungen' . '</a><br />' .

              '  </div>' .
              '</div>';

      $oscTemplate->addBlock($data, $this->group);
    }

    function isEnabled() {
      return $this->enabled;
    }

    function check() {
      return defined('MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_STATUS');
    }

    function install() {
      tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " (configuration_title, configuration_key, configuration_value, configuration_description, configuration_group_id, sort_order, set_function, date_added) values ('Enable Information Module', 'MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_STATUS', 'True', 'Do you want to add the module to your shop?', '6', '1', 'tep_cfg_select_option(array(\'True\', \'False\'), ', now())");
      tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " (configuration_title, configuration_key, configuration_value, configuration_description, configuration_group_id, sort_order, set_function, date_added) values ('Content Placement', 'MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_CONTENT_PLACEMENT', 'Left Column', 'Should the module be loaded in the left or right column?', '6', '1', 'tep_cfg_select_option(array(\'Left Column\', \'Right Column\'), ', now())");
      tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " (configuration_title, configuration_key, configuration_value, configuration_description, configuration_group_id, sort_order, date_added) values ('Sort Order', 'MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_SORT_ORDER', '0', 'Sort order of display. Lowest is displayed first.', '6', '0', now())");
    }

    function remove() {
      tep_db_query("delete from " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " where configuration_key in ('" . implode("', '", $this->keys()) . "')");
    }

    function keys() {
      return array('MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_STATUS', 'MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_CONTENT_PLACEMENT', 'MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_SORT_ORDER');
    }
  }
?>
```

I need to integrate it some where in function

```
function execute() {
      global $oscTemplate;

      $data = '<div class="ui-widget infoBoxContainer mj-information">' .
              '  <div class="ui-widget-header infoBoxHeading">' . MODULE_BOXES_GALLERY_BOX_TITLE . '</div>' .
              '  <div class="ui-widget-content infoBoxContents">' .
              '    <p>Lesen Sie hier was unsere Kunden über uns sagen: </p>' .
              '    <a href="bewertungen.php">' . 'Alle Kundenmeinungen' . '</a><br />' .

              '  </div>' .
              '</div>';

      $oscTemplate->addBlock($data, $this->group);
    }
```

Comment: You say "result return only errors". What errors?

Comment: When I mix the my own code with the cod from oscommerce I made something wrong because it returns nothing and only errors that I have some mistakes in my code, for example the "}" is not expected

Comment: So your question is about a syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you had integrated the WP environment into OSC or vise versa but to call WP functions in OSC you have to setup the WP environment first...for example, call this in your OSC application_top.php

```
require('wp_dir/wp-load.php');
```

It seems like you are making calls directly to WP, but I have been doing this by integrating WP into OSC, and then just using shortcodes to display stuffs I need from WP. I have couple [WP/OSC examples](http://www.clustersolutions.net/2015/05/06/integrating-wordpress-into-oscommerce/) online and I hope they can be helpful to you.